# Find area under ROC curve, given X and Y vectors of coordinates, use trapezium rule, answer must be within absolute error of x10^-9

Tags: python, python-3.x, area, curve, roc

Given x = [0.00,0.20,0.33,0.43,0.63,0.66,1.00], 
y = [0.00,0.25,0.25,0.50,0.50,1.00,1.00]

I need to write a function, taking X and Y as arguments.
Trapezium rule must be used.

What I am struggling with is - how to ensure the answer that has an absolute error of lower than x10^-9.
Since this is discrete data, how am I to calculate an error?

Comment: Why would there be any error at all, if you already have all the coordinates involved? Your coordinates describe six intervals, with each interval a simple triangle on top of a rectangle. Why would there be an error in your area calculation? Sure, there might be an error with respect to the "true" function, but that's not what you're asking about.